# How to restore an individual file from Time Machine using CLI (MacOS)

Tags: backup, command-line, time-machine, restore, ssh

How can I restore a single file from an old Time Machine backup using only the Command Line Interface?

I took a snapshot of my MacOS system using Time Machine some time ago, and I'd like to restore just one file from it.

Also, I don't have GUI access to this box; only ssh (with root privilege).

Is it possible to restore just one file from a Time Machine backup using the CLI over SSH? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can browse to the files directly and restore them with the `rsync` command.

#### Determine path to Backups

First, list all of your existing backups using `tmutil listbackups`

```
user@host ~ % tmutil listbackups
/Volumes/externalBackups/Backups.backupdb/host/2020-06-17-095312
/Volumes/externalBackups/Backups.backupdb/host/2020-06-18-222034
/Volumes/externalBackups/Backups.backupdb/host/2020-06-21-110109
user@host ~ %
```

#### Enter Backup Directory

Next, `cd` into one of the above directories (the one from which you want to restore)

```
user@host ~ % cd /Volumes/externalBackups/Backups.backupdb/host/2020-06-21-110109
user@host 2020-06-21-110109 %
```

#### Enter Backup's Data Directory

There should be a `- Data` directory with the data from this particular Time Machine backup. In this case, our backups were created with `tmutil startbackup`, so the Data Directory is `Untitled - Data`

```
user@host 2020-06-21-110109 % ls | grep -i Data
Untitled - Data
user@host 2020-06-21-110109 % 

user@host 2020-06-21-110109 % cd "Untitled - Data"
user@host Untitled - Data %
```

#### Restore with `rsync`

You can restore a given file with `rsync`. For example, to restore the `/private/etc/resolv.conf` file to your system, you can now execute the following

```
user@host Untitled - Data % sudo rsync -av --progress private/etc/resolv.conf /private/etc/resolv.conf
...
user@host Untitled - Data %
```

Comment: Personally I prefer using `rsync` rather than `cp`.  However, since the intention is to use the `cp` command to restore a file from a "backup", I would recommend using `cp -p`.  This way the restored file preserve the following attributes of each source file in the copy: modification time, access time, file flags, file mode, user ID, and group ID, as allowed by permissions.

Comment: Yes to the above, and ideally `rsync -a` for the same reason @wch1zpink mentioned.

Comment: changed to rsync. I also prefer it, but I wasn't sure if it was installed by default in MacOS.

Comment: `ls *[dD]ata*` might be more elegant than using `grep`. You can even make a (not actually very bold) assumption and just type `cd *[dD]ata*`.

Comment: Also, did you run `sudo -s` at the beginning? The `cp`/`rsync` at the end most likely will fail for non-root users (depends on the file to be copied of course).

Comment: rsync is installed by default in macOS BUT it is an old version and does not support all ACL. You really should install a newer version (rsync changed to GPLv3 and Apple provide the last GPL 2 version)

Comment: I wonder if it would be safer to use `ditto` because it copies meta-data ("resource forks, extended attributes, Access Control Lists (ACLs), as well as quarantine bits")—or, these things only apply to HFS and not APFS

Answer (score 4):

#### Use `tmutil restore`

As a long time Unix fan I do love `rsync`.
Using the native `rsync` for this purpose, even in macOS Ventura 13.2, does have some downsides though:

1. As suggested in a [comment by
   huyz](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/442475/how-to-restore-an-individual-file-from-time-machine-using-cli-macos#comment648780_442479), `rsync`
   isn't macOS aware. I have found that it won't copy any of the
   extended attributes of files that you use it to restore.
2. `rsync` isn't a Time Machine utility program that's Time Machine
   aware, and seems unlikely to receive specific support from Apple
   for the purpose of restoring files from Time Machine.

Alternatively, use `tmutil`.

`tmutil` is the Apple provided Time Machine command line utility supporting the `restore` action (since at least macOS 10.15):

```sh
tmutil restore src ... dst
```

The manual page for `tmutil` for the restore action says:

> **restore** [-v] *src* *...* *dst*
>
> Restore the item *src*, which is inside a backup, to the location *dst*. The *dst* argument mimics the destination path semantics of the **cp** tool. You may provide multiple source paths to restore. The last path argument must be a destination.
>
> When using the **restore** verb, **tmutil** behaves largely like Finder. Custom Time Machine metadata (extended security and other) will be removed from the restored data, and other metadata will be preserved.
>
> Root and Full Disk Access privileges may be required to perform restores. When restoring with **tmutil** as root, ownership of the restored items will match the state of the items in the backup.

Here's an example of what this looks like. This is for a restore of the contents of my other Mac's (`Other System`) `Downloads` folder. And my shell is in the folder of that backup I wanted to restore from:

```sh
Downloads $ tmutil restore * ~/Downloads 
Total copied: 2273.96 MB (2384424593 bytes)
Items copied: 76143
Downloads $ pwd
/Volumes/My Disk 1/Backups.backupdb/Other System/Latest/Macintosh HD - Data/Users/louis/Downloads
Downloads $ ls -l@ manual.docx            
-rw-r--r--@ 99 louis  staff  381577 Dec  5  2015 manual.docx
    com.apple.finder.copy.source.checksum#N      4 
    com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot      50 
    com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot      50 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate        53 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms       218 
    com.apple.quarantine        57 
Downloads $ ls -l@ ~/Downloads/manual.docx            
-rw-r--r--@ 1 louis  staff  381577 Dec  5  2015 /Users/louis/Downloads/manual.docx
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate        53 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms       218 
    com.apple.quarantine        57 
Downloads $ tmutil compare manual.docx ~/Downloads/manual.docx 

-------------------------------------
Added:         0B
Removed:       0B
Changed:       0B
Downloads $
```

The command line *src* *...* and *dst* arguments in this regard are just like what I'd use for `rsync` or `cp`. The difference being that using `tmutil restore`, all of the metadata for the files appear to be preserved with the exception of "Time Machine metadata" - which I take to be metadata that appears associated with the backup folder files but not with the original nor restored files. Thus the restored files and their metadata look to me to be exactly what they had been on the original computer from where they'd been backed up from.

Comment: Can you please provide an example execution in your answer?

Comment: @MichaelAltfield I liked your suggestion and have edited my answer with additional details like an example execution.

Answer (score -1):

If you find a GUI easier to navigate, you should be able to use an FTP client (Transmit, Filezilla, Cyberduck, etc.) and connect to your Time Machine backup via sftp.

Comment: Because original poster stated they didn’t have GUI access but did have SSH, which means an SFTP client would provide GUI access. Not necessarily going to be obvious to all users this is an option. I’ve used the same approach with my own TimeMachine backup, to access specific files remotely from my home server via SFTP. Poster asked how to pull one file over SSH. This is a viable option.